# Linq to Sql escape WHERE clause

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, linq-to-sql

I have this Linq-to-SQL query

```
  DaynamicContext.Log = new System.IO.StreamWriter("f:\\linq-to-sql.txt") { AutoFlush = true })
  var tt = DaynamicContext.GetTable(tbl);
  var query = ((from c in tt where c.IsDeleted != true select c.Id).Take(1)).ToList();
```

The result of final query is correct is got only single Id.

[image]

The problem when I have big data I got out of memory exception.

When I checked the generated query

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[CreatedBy], [t0].[CreatedDate], [t0].[ModifiedBy], 
[t0].[ModifiedDate], [t0].[IsDeleted], [t0].[UntileTime], [t0].[Desktop], 
[t0].[Laptop], [t0].[Title], [t0].[Responsive], [t0].[Mobile], [t0].[ActiveTime],
[t0].[Tablet]
FROM [Countent_FreeArea] AS [t0]
```

it seems like Linq-to-SQL is getting all data from database and filtering it on memory.

```
public class Context
{
    private DataContext daynamicContext;
    public DataContext DaynamicContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (daynamicContext == null)
            {
                System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connectionStrings = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
                daynamicContext = new DataContext(connectionStrings["connectionStrings"].ToString());
            }
            return daynamicContext;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the `.GetTable()` method seems to me to be a call to *get the whole table* which is exactly what you're seeing .....

Comment: GetTable() method Return "ITable" which is not invoke the get.
I tried to remove the query line and keep Just GetTable() the result no query will  generated

Comment: Can you show us what `DaynamicContext` is??

Comment: I edit the question to show the daynamicContext
and the tbl object is runtime generated class

Answer (score 0):

The GetTable method will fetch the whole table first and then select the first value from the list. Also instead of using `Take()`, use `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: GetTable() method Return "ITable" which is not invoke the get. I tried to remove the query line and keep Just GetTable() the result no query will generated

Comment: tried removing the Take? Also Why are you converting it to as enumerable and then to a list?